# Refer to installed PCL (ARM)

Tags: slam, navigation, ccny-rgbd, viso2-ros, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i was able to install PCL 1.7.0 on my ARM based PandaBoard.

If I now try to install different ROS stacks that depend on PCL it is always telling me that ROS is not able to find PCL. (I tried for example to install RGBD, Navigation, viso2_ros...)

Could anyone explain how do I refer to the PCL in the right way so that it is found by ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95876/refer-to-installed-pcl-(arm)/) by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-14**:
What version of ROS are you trying to use?

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-11-15**:
i used ROS groovy, but i upgraded now to hydro and there it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, In Groovy ROS uses a custom packaged version of PCL. In Hydro it uses the system installed version.  So upgrading to Hydro is the easiest solution.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-11-16**:
upgrading to hydro was really the best thing that i could do on my arm pandaboard.
most things work fine, but it's stillt not perfect.
today i tried to install ccny and i get again the error that PCL is not found, cause i have to built that on my own. any ideas to set THIS one to the right refer?